# cannot find symbol java calculation code

Tags: java, linux, terminal, symbols

I'm totally noob in java. Just getting started. some please help me get this code. trying to write a code to perform calculation but it shows cannot find symbol.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cal {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a, b, r;
        String op;
        System.out.print("Choose one : add, sub, mul, div ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        op = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the value : ");
        Scanner val = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = val.nextInt();
        b = val.nextInt();
        if (op == add) {
            r = a + b;
            System.out.println(r);
        } else if (op == sub) {
            r = a - b;
            System.out.println(r);
        } else if (op == mul) {
            r = a * b;
            System.out.println(r);
        } else if (op == div) {
            r = a / b;
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can not find what symbol? What kind of error do you get? At what line of code?

Comment: Please post your stacktrace. `if (op == add)` Where did the `add` variable come from? Same for `sub` and `mul` and `div`.

Comment: For comparing strings you cannot use `op == add` you need to use `op.equals("add")`.

Answer (score 5):

```
 if (op == add)
```

This and the other ones are the culprits. First of all, String values have to be inside `"`. Also, == is not a good equality check for String.

```
if ("add".equals(op))
```

would be better.

The same goes for the other conditions of course.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have symbols add, sub ... Instead compare with string "add", "sub" ...

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Cannot resolve symbol` on `add, sub, mul, div` because written like this they have to be variable, and they aren't not, you need for example

```
String add = "add";
```

---

Then for `String comparison` you need to use `equals` instead of `==` :

```
if("add".equals(op)){...}
```

---

Also to avoid multiple `if` (also use the print outside to avoid `duplicate code`) to find what `op` is equal to, you can use a switch construction :

```
switch (op) {
        case "add":
            r = a + b;
            break;
        case "sub":
            r = a - b;
            break;
        case "mul":
            r = a * b;
            break;
        case "div":
            r = a / b;
            break;
}
System.out.println(r);
```